# UV Map is badly placed on model

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I am trying to use texture paint to paint the bottom half of the wick white. But as you can see the has a very bad position on the model where a few pixel on the UV Map cover half of the model. How can I fix that?

[image]

I've tried to move the map with this nodes:

[image]

It moves the map but I was not able to figure out it's orientation in any way, or how (direction, rotation) I should move it.

Comment: Hi :). You fix that by unwrapping the model again.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean with that. How do I unwrap it? I'm sorry I'm very new to blender.